# Asp.net Mvc: Jquery post array + anti forgery token

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, arrays

how do I post an array to an action on my controler with the anti forgery token.

This is my Jquery postdata:

```
var postData = { '__RequestVerificationToken': $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val(), 'productIds': IDs };
```

this is my Jquery post:

```
$.post("MyProducts/DeleteProduct" , postData, function(data) { });
```

This is my action:

```
public void DeleteProduct(List<int> productIds)
    {
        foreach (int i in productIds)
        {
            _repository.DeleteProduct(i, null);
        }        
    }
```

I also use an object to store my anti forgery token and I wonder how I can use that with the postdata.

This is the token object:

```
var token = { '__RequestVerificationToken': $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() };
```

Kind regards

Comment: might be useful... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074199/jquery-ajax-calls-and-the-html-antiforgerytoken/4074289

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var ids = [1,2];

var data = {
__RequestVerificationToken : token,
productIds : ids
};

$.post(url, data, function() ...
```

where token is the var you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have all your product IDs in the HTML it would be much easier to use [jqueryForm plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started):

```
$("form").ajaxSubmit({url: "MyProducts/DeleteProduct", success: function(response) {
  // Handle the response
}})
```

Comment: That would mean I have to add a second form to my view and a second AntiForgeryToken I guess. Also the IDs are extracted from a table row. The IDs are like this: id="productRow-1", id="productRow-2, ...