# Override jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there way to override jQuery's core functions ?
Say I wanted to add an alert(this.length) in size: function()
Instead of adding it in the source

```
size: function() {
    alert(this.length)
    return this.length;
},
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to do something like this :

```
if (console)
{
    console.log("Size of div = " + $("div").size());
    var oSize = jQuery.fn.size;
    jQuery.fn.size = function()
    {
        alert(this.length);

        // Now go back to jQuery's original size()
        return oSize(this);        
    }
    console.log("Size of div = " + $("div").size());
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You *almost* had it, you need to set the `this` reference inside of the old `size` function to be the `this` reference in the override function, like this:

```
var oSize = jQuery.fn.size;
jQuery.fn.size = function() {
    alert(this.length);

    // Now go back to jQuery's original size()
    return oSize.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

The way this works is `Function` instances have a method called `apply`, whose purpose is to arbitrarily override the inner `this` reference inside of the function's body.

So, as an example:

```
var f = function() { console.log(this); }
f.apply("Hello World", null); //prints "Hello World" to the console
```

Comment: Any particular reason why this doesnt work for init ?
(function($)
{
    var _o_init = jQuery.fn.init;
    jQuery.fn.init = function(selector, context)
    {
        if (console) console.log("Function Call : init");
        return _o_init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})(jQuery);

Comment: did the same with the data function.. saved my day

Answer (score 1):

You can override plugins method by prototype it in a separate file without modifying original source file as below::

```
(function ($) {
    $.ui.draggable.prototype._mouseDrag = function(event, noPropagation) {

         // Your Code
    },

    $.ui.resizable.prototype._mouseDrag = function(event) {
            // Your code
    }   
}(jQuery));
```

Now put your logic here or original code with your new idea that is needed in your project.