# fadeToggle jQuery callback before, not after

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-callback

Is there a way to assign a callback before the fade animation occurs in fadeToggle? I am adjusting scroll positions and would like to adjust it before the object appears, not after.

Comment: If you know the size of the object, what about simply adjusting the scroll positions before calling fadeToggle?

Comment: I tried that, but the reason I need to adjust scrollbars is because setting display: none (which occurs with fadeToggle as far as I know) causes scrollbars to reset afterwards. If you adjust before, and the object is hidden, when it appears the scroll position won't be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is call your function, or run any code, directly after fadeToggle:

```
element.fadeToggle('fast');
element.scrollTop(300);
```

This will immediately set the scroll position, and the fade affect will follow.

Here is what I specifically had: visible and hidden are elements I just named as vars.

```
visible.fadeToggle('fast', function() {
    hidden.fadeToggle('fast');
    hidden.scrollTop(top_value);
});
```

When visible is hidden, the callback is invoked and the hidden element becomes visible. The scroll position is set immediately after, so you see the change before the fade has completed. This way you have a fluid fade and keep the scroll positions of both elements the same.

Answer (score 1):

Call back gives you a way to perform something after the given action has completed. If you need to do something before operation (fading)  just **do it** before calling the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

would the `fadeToggle` override be an option for you ? if so then click the link below :)

[Override jQuery functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536788/override-jquery-functions)