# fire a custom event on console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

Is there a way to fire an event on every `console.log()` which will include either the parameters passed in the log function or the data returned by it? What I want to do is track every `console.log` execution and pass the information in a `div` of the page.

I don't mind whether it's a JavaScript or a JQuery answer since I'm using both in this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript">
    // cache a reference to the log method on the console object
    var _consoleLog = console.log;

    // replace the existing log method on the console object
    console.log = function() {
            // your custom action
        alert(arguments[0]);

            // pass control to the cached log method
        return _consoleLog.apply(console, arguments);
    };

    // quick test
    console.log("hello");
</script>
```

This will do the trick

Comment: wrong line number

Comment: What line number?

Comment: when you go with console.log, browser will show where it is (line number). if you go with the generic console log, browser shows which line the console.log is called at. if you do this wrap, it always shows the line number of `return _consoleLog.apply`

Answer (score 0):

[Override jQuery functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536788/override-jquery-functions)

Try something like this:

```
var doSomethingElse = function(data) {
  $("#output").html(data);
};
var f = function() { 
  console.log(this); 
  doSomethingElse(this);
};
f.apply("Hello World", null);
```