# Customize jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible add some function to jquery functions like hide() or show()? The objective is always that I use the function hide(), it will execute jquery base and my own function.
If yes, can you show me how? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could override the function. Check [Override jQuery functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536788/override-jquery-functions) for a more detailed answer.

Edit: 
`jQuery.fn.show = function() {
    // Your custom code
}`

But I wouldn't override jQuery's methods when you could create your own. Overriding would very likely cause unexpected behavior in plugins.

Comment: I was just about to write this out by hand, not knowing that solution existed.