# Override jQuery functions simply by extending?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is related to, but not a duplicate of, another SO Q&A [Override jQuery functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536788/override-jquery-functions).

It is clear from the answer to the above question that the pattern to override a jQuery function is:

```
(function($){

    // store original reference to the method
    var _old = $.fn.method;

    $.fn.method = function(arg1,arg2){

        if ( ... condition ... ) {
           return  ....
        } else {           // do the default
           return _old.apply(this,arguments);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

## ***But why!?***

I've been able to override a jQuery function simply by defining a function of the same name as the function to be overridden, within `$.extend` or `$.fn.extend`.

Consider this:

```
// random example showing jquery function overriding
$.fn.extend({
    hide: function() {
        $(this).css({"color":"red"});
    }
});

$("#test").hide(); // this will actually paint the #test element red!
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5V9rv/)

**I'd like to understand why `_old.apply(this,arguments)` would be the preferred way to override a jQuery function, as listed [here](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/) and [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1624-ask-ben-overriding-core-jquery-methods.htm).**

Comment: So what's the problem you're having?

Comment: `fn` is jQuery's shortcut for `prototype`, so you can just do `$.fn.hide` (or `$.prototype.hide`) to create a new prototyped property called `hide` that overrides the previous `hide`, and to understand that you should probably head over to MDN and read about objects and prototypes, as this has little to do with jQuery.

Comment: The problem is that I'm missing the piece that justifies why `.apply` would be the preferred way to override a jQuery function.

Comment: Obviously the jQuery arguments, are provided in array.
Instead of overriding I would use middle man: http://tech.zumba.com/middleman.js/

Answer (score 2):

```
(function($){

    // store original reference to the method
    // stored locally
    var _old = $.fn.method;

    $.fn.method = function(arg1,arg2){

        if ( ... condition ... ) {
           return  ....
        } else {           // do the default
           // call apply method, in order to pass the this context.
           return _old.apply(this,arguments);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Here in the above code, we are calling an anonymous function, in which we are declaring a local variable `_old`. When this anonymous function execute, it save the `_old` method reference and form a `closure`. 
Now, when we call the new method, i.e,

```
    $.fn.method = function(arg1,arg2){
       if ( ... condition ... ) {
           return  ....
        } else {           // do the default
           return _old.apply(this,arguments);
        }
    };
```

we also have an access to `_old` method, since its scope exists in the current context. And then, we can use it inside the new method.

Here we are calling `_old` method with the help of `apply`, because we want to have the same `this` context for that as well.

With this approach, we can easily override the `jQuery` method by preserving its original functionality.

Answer (score 1):

From glancing at references provided at original post, summary of pattern *could* be to keep both "old" and "new" methods available ?

Edit, updated

> *Sorry, I don't get this. As far as I see, the reference to the overridden method is saved in a local variable in a closure is
>   unquestionably lost outside the closure. Can you explain how the "old"
>   method is still available? –SNag*
>
> I'd like to understand why _old.apply(this,arguments) would be the
>   preferred way to override a jQuery function, as listed [here](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/) and
>   [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1624-ask-ben-overriding-core-jquery-methods.htm).

Utilizing pattern at 1st link , above , if interpret pieces correctly, appear `arguments` `test` within `if` statement of jquery method within "self-executing anonymous function" determine return value of "old" or "new" (newly included; override) jquery method ?

i.e.g., try

html

```
<div>abc</div>
```

js

```
// See http://www.paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/ , at
// `First we start off with a self-executing anonymous function,
// that makes a happy closure while remapping jQuery to $:`

// `closure` start
    (function ($) {
        // jquery `.css()`
        var _oldcss = $.fn.css;
        // jquery `.hide()`
        var _oldhide = $.fn.hide;

        // "new" `.css()`
        $.fn.css = function (prop, value) {
            // "new" `.css()` `test`
            if (/^background-?color$/i.test(prop) 
                && value.toLowerCase() === 'burnt sienna') {
                return _oldcss.call(this, prop, '#EA7E5D');
            } else {
                return _oldcss.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        };

        // "new" `.hide()`
        $.fn.hide = function (prop, value) {
            // "new" `.hide()` `test` 
            if (/color/i.test(prop) && /[a-f]|[0-9]/i.test(value)) {
                return $.fn.css.call(this, prop, value);
            } else {
                return _oldhide.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        };
    })(jQuery);
    // `closure` stop

    // and using it...
    // "new" `.css()`
    jQuery(document.body).css('backgroundColor', 'burnt sienna');
    // "old" `.css()`
    $("div").css("color", "yellow");
    // "old" `.hide()`
    $("div").hide(7500, function () {
        // "old" `.css()`
        $(document.body)
            .css({
            "transition": "background 2s",
            "background": "#edd452"
        })
        .find($("div")).show(2500)
        // "new" `.hide()`
        .hide("color", "red")
    });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/5bEe4/

Comment: Sorry, I don't get this. As far as I see, the reference to the overridden method is saved in a local variable in a closure is unquestionably lost outside the closure. Can you explain how the "old" method is still available?

Comment: @SNag:Reference of a overridden method is saved in a local variable, which is available inside the anonymous function(thus form a closure). once you called new method, it will call the `_old` method( as its scope is still present). Here, `apply` is used to pass the original(current) `this` reference, so that its context is available on the `_old` method. The former way is used, because here you can override the method by preserving its original functionality, so that original `jQuery` functionality doesn't break.

Comment: @MohitPandey: Your comment makes a lot of sense. If you could write out a complete answer, I'd be glad to accept it! Thanks!