# How to test if a URL string is absolute or relative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, url

How can I test a URL if it is a relative or absolute path in Javascript or jQuery? I want to handle accordingly depending if the passed in URL is a local or external path.

```
if (urlString starts with http:// or https://)
 //do this
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
var pat = /^https?:\/\//i;
if (pat.test(urlString))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

For protocol relative urls, use this regex:

`/^https?:\/\/|^\/\//i`

Comment: This answers the asked question but you may also want to consider [protocol relative urls](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) which start with `//`.

Comment: What if url contains "file://"? BOOM! Tragedy. Answer from @Philipp is more reliable.

Comment: The accepted answer is invalid, at least in 2019. Chrome happily accepts http:example.com.

Answer (score 224):

### FAST

If you only need to test for `http://` or `https://` then the *most efficient* way is:

```
if (urlString.indexOf('http://') === 0 || urlString.indexOf('https://') === 0)
```

---

### UNIVERSAL

However, I would suggest a *more universal, non case-sensitive, protocol-agnostic* approach:

```
var r = new RegExp('^(?:[a-z+]+:)?//', 'i');
r.test('http://example.com'); // true - regular http absolute URL
r.test('HTTP://EXAMPLE.COM'); // true - HTTP upper-case absolute URL
r.test('https://www.exmaple.com'); // true - secure http absolute URL
r.test('ftp://example.com/file.txt'); // true - file transfer absolute URL
r.test('//cdn.example.com/lib.js'); // true - protocol-relative absolute URL
r.test('git+ssh://example.con/item'); // true - absolute URL with '+' in scheme
r.test('/myfolder/test.txt'); // false - relative URL
r.test('test'); // false - also relative URL
```

---

#### Explain the RegExp

```
^(?:[a-z+]+:)?//
```

`^` - beginning of the string
`(?:` - beginning of a non-captured group
  `[a-z+]+` - any character of 'a' to 'z' or "+" 1 or more times
  `:` - string (colon character)
`)?` - end of the non-captured group. Group appearing 0 or 1 times
`//` - string (two forward slash characters)
`'i'` - non case-sensitive flag

Comment: why a-z ? doesn't domain name can have 0-9 and hyphen in domain name?

Comment: right, but we are not checking for domain name here, are we? This will still work: `/^(?:[a-z]+:)?\/\//i.test('https://www.ex-maple-123.com');`

Comment: Can scheme contain digits? We all know http, https, ftp, and mailto.  Anyone define custom schemes for internal tools?  I think OneNote and Outlook do on Windows.

Comment: This doesn't account for browser behavior.  The browser will remove leading spaces.  Start with trim?

Comment: good points yzorg. You would have to use ``var r = new RegExp('^\\s*(?:[a-z0-9]+:)?//', 'i')``

Comment: The last 2 slashes are unescaped. `//` = `\/\/`

Comment: you would only want to escape them if delimiters are used. Like in my comment from  Jan 6 at 19:28  above

Comment: This does not capture "mailto:" URLs. Not that I know if mailto URLs are absolute or relative ;-)

Comment: nice but there is a problem, it does not handle special links like tel: mailto: sms:

Comment: This is a test for __absolute__ URLs, but cannot be used to test for __relative__ urls. As noted above, things like `mailto:...`, `about:...` & `sms:...` will cause false positives when trying to find *relative* paths (also, things that are invalid *Locations*).

Comment: `mailto:`, etc. are not URLs but rather URIs and thus should be handled differently if not blocked entirely.

Comment: `view-source:` doesn't match.

Comment: This answer fails on `https:example.com`. This URL works fine at least in Chrome.

Comment: `new RegExp('^(//|[a-z]+:)', 'i')` should work for matching `mailto:`, `about:`, `tel:`, etc. including the existing test cases. The idea here is to still provide for protocol-relative absolute URLs and while extending existing functionality of detecting absolute URLs without requiring a check for the double forward slashes (`//`). Thus, `r.test('mailto:hi@example.com') === true`, `r.test('https:example.com') === true`, and so forth.

Comment: This won't work for URLs like: `git+ssh://example.com:1231/some/thing`: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-4.3

Comment: @IwanAucamp good point - feel free to update your non-captured group with an escaped plus, i.e. replace `[a-z]+` with `[a-z\+]+`

Comment: @IwanAucamp I edited for that. Nice catch.

Comment: @Professorofprogramming it does, look: `(new RegExp('^(?:[a-z+]+:)?//', 'i')).test('file:///example.com/item'); // true` - the third slash is out of the regex.

Answer (score 45):

Depending on your needs, I think that a more reliable way to determine this is to use the [built-in URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to construct a couple URL objects and compare origins.

```
new URL(document.baseURI).origin === new URL(urlToTest, document.baseURI).origin;
```

This allows the browser to parse and figure all this out for you, without having to worry about the side effects of edge cases.

Comment: This is a great new addition to the other more duck-typing solutions. However I wonder why you do not suggest `new URL(document.baseURI).origin === new URL(urlToTest,document.baseURI).origin` ? Would this not be more apt for those cases where the webpage contains a [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) ?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace Yes, good idea!  I've updated the answer with your improvements.

Comment: I've downvoted every regex-based answer and upvoted every one that uses built-in classes like `URL`. This is the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this actually works – `new URL(urlToTest, document.baseURI).origin` will always return the same, regardless of whether the URL is absolute or relative

Comment: @DavidChouinard It does work.  Please use the full line of code.  Constructing the URL object from the `urlToTest` allows the browser to determine what the `origin` should be for that URL.  It doesn't matter if it's a full URL matching the same origin... as long as it matches that origin, you can determine if it's relative to the current origin.

Answer (score 32):

## Original Answer

A very **fast** and very **flexible** check is:

```
if (url.indexOf('://') > 0 || url.indexOf('//') === 0 ) {
    // URL is absolute; either "http://example.com" or "//example.com"
} else {
    // URL is relative
}
```

This will recognize an absolute URL, if:

- URL contains "://" anywhere *after* the first character, or
- URL starts with "//" (protocol relative)

---

- No regex.
- No jQuery or other dependency.
- No hardcoded protocol names that make the condition case sensitive.
- No string manipulation (e.g. toLowerCase or similar).
- Only checks for "relative or absolute" but does not make any other sanity checks, can be used for web URLs or any internal protocol.

---

## Update 1 (full function example)

Here is a quick **function** that returns true/false for the given URL:

```
function isUrlAbsolute(url) { 
    return (url.indexOf('://') > 0 || url.indexOf('//') === 0);
}
```

And same in ES6:

```
const isUrlAbsolute = (url) => (url.indexOf('://') > 0 || url.indexOf('//') === 0)
```

---

## Update 2 (URLs inside URL param)

To additionally address URLs in format `/redirect?target=http://example.org` I recommend to use this code:

```
function isUrlAbsolute(url) {
    if (url.indexOf('//') === 0) {return true;} // URL is protocol-relative (= absolute)
    if (url.indexOf('://') === -1) {return false;} // URL has no protocol (= relative)
    if (url.indexOf('.') === -1) {return false;} // URL does not contain a dot, i.e. no TLD (= relative, possibly REST)
    if (url.indexOf('/') === -1) {return false;} // URL does not contain a single slash (= relative)
    if (url.indexOf(':') > url.indexOf('/')) {return false;} // The first colon comes after the first slash (= relative)
    if (url.indexOf('://') < url.indexOf('.')) {return true;} // Protocol is defined before first dot (= absolute)
    return false; // Anything else must be relative
}
```

And the same in short form and ES 6

```
// Traditional JS, shortened
function isUrlAbsolute(url) {
    return url.indexOf('//') === 0 ? true : url.indexOf('://') === -1 ? false : url.indexOf('.') === -1 ? false : url.indexOf('/') === -1 ? false : url.indexOf(':') > url.indexOf('/') ? false : url.indexOf('://') < url.indexOf('.') ? true : false;
}

// ES 6
const isUrlAbsolute = (url) => (url.indexOf('//') === 0 ? true : url.indexOf('://') === -1 ? false : url.indexOf('.') === -1 ? false : url.indexOf('/') === -1 ? false : url.indexOf(':') > url.indexOf('/') ? false : url.indexOf('://') < url.indexOf('.') ? true : false)
```

Here are some test cases:

```
// Test
console.log( isUrlAbsolute('http://stackoverflow.com') ) // -> true
console.log( isUrlAbsolute('//stackoverflow.com') ) // -> true
console.log( isUrlAbsolute('stackoverflow.com') ) // -> false
console.log( isUrlAbsolute('Ftp://example.net') ) // -> true
console.log( isUrlAbsolute('/redirect?target=http://example.org') ) // -> false
```

---

## Update 3 (clarify relative URLs)

I've seen a few comments about invalid output:

- *Solution returns false for `localhost`*
- *Answer fails on `http:example.com`*

However, **those URLs are indeed relative URLs**. It's easy to test:

> 1. Create some folders on your localhost webroot, say `a/b/c/`
> 2. Create an index.html file and place following link into it: `<a href="localhost">test</a>`
> 3. Open the index page in your browser: http://localhost/a/b/c/index.html and click on the link. You will end on http://localhost/a/b/c/localhost (and not on http://localhost)
> 4. Same happens when placing the link `http:example.com` into your index.html file. You end on http://localhost/a/b/c/example.com instead of http://example.com

Comment: Nope. I was just tracking down a bug in my project and discovered it was too such a function. The webpage had a url like  `/redirect?target=http://example.org`

Comment: @BeniBela, you could fix this by using ```function isUrlAbsolute(url) { var firstSlash = url.indexOf('/'); var colonDoubleSlash = url.indexOf('://');
    return ((firstSlash > 0 && colonDoubleSlash > 0 && colonDoubleSlash < firstSlash) || url.indexOf('//') === 0);
}```

Comment: @BeniBela You are right, this can happen in some cases. I updated the code above to handle this. However, I strongly suggest to url-encode all query params, i.e. to use `/redirect?target=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com`

Comment: This answers the question, but it doesn't really test for whether the input is absolute. For example, "/aaa/bbb" comes back as "relative", when it's actually absolute.

Comment: @N73k actually I consider your example "/aaa/bbb" relative to the domain. I.e. if you have `<img src="/aaa/bbb">` on on site1.com and site2.com both images are different (i.e. relative). While `<img src="//site1.com/aaa/bbb">`is identical for all domains (which is absolute)

Comment: This answer fails on `http:example.com`. This URL works fine at least in Chrome 76.

Comment: @GeneS your URL is relative. You can test it: create the file `example.org/a/b/c/index.html`. Add the link `<a href="http:example.org/a>go to a</a>` in the index file and open it. the link will point to `http://example.org/a/b/c/example.org/a` - besides: _Its use should be avoided but is allowed for backward compatibility_ (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5.4.2)

Comment: @molsson - It's surprising, but the result is correct. The URL `localhost` is indeed relative. However, `http://localhost` is absolute... You can test it (see my previous comment for an example)

Comment: @Phillipp. Nope, that's an absolute URL. Just did what you suggested and Chrome 76 opened `http://example.org/a`

Comment: Chrome also follows an invalid url `http:/example.com`.

Comment: Maybe a difference between Mac and Windows? I've also tested it in Chrome, and it was treated as relative URL for me. Also the RFC states, that `"http:g" = "http://a/b/c/g"`. Possibly it's best to use the `//` to ensure consistent behavior ;-)

Comment: Actually the difference is due to the origin URL. If the page is loaded from file:///, then the url 'http:example.com' is treated as absolute. It's treated as relative otherwise.

Comment: `isUrlAbsolute('redirect')` gives `false`, which is correct, but `isUrlAbsolute('redirect?target=http://example.org')` gives `true`, which is not correct.

I'm thinking it would be useful to check if the `://` comes after a `?` or a `#`… is there any situation where that would conflict with something?

Comment: Fails with test case: `http://somehostname`  which is absolute. Not all host names have dots in them.

Answer (score 20):

Use a regex:

```
if (/^(?:[a-z]+:)?\/\//i.test(url))
```

Comment: this seems to be the most universal answer. Only lacks a protocol-relative URL (e.g. //cdn.example.com/libary.js)

Comment: Although the question only mentions http and https, a general solution might also have to take into account a "mailto:" url, which doesn't have forward slashes.

Comment: @mikebridge are you saying that `mailto:` can be absolute or relative sometimes?

Comment: @Geo: No; he's saying that `mailto:` is absolute even though it has no `/` characters.

Comment: please join chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44712/absolute-or-relative-url

Comment: This answer fails on `http:example.com`. This URL works fine at least in Chrome.

Answer (score 12):

## Even more Universal RFC-compliant URI approach:

`(?:^[a-z][a-z0-9+\.-]*:|\/\/)` [regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/nR2yL6/3)

The other solutions listed here would fail for links like `mailto:evan@nylas.com`

**RFC 3986** defines a **Scheme** as:

`scheme      = ALPHA *( ALPHA / DIGIT / "+" / "-" / "." )`

**3.1.  Scheme**
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1

While the protocol-relative url is technically valid as per section 4.2, Paul Irish has swung back the other way and considers this an anti-pattern. See http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

**4.2.  Relative Reference**
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2

If you'd like the regex without protocol-relative url's use:

`^[a-z][a-z0-9+\.-]*:`

To see a full list of other types of valid uri edge cases, check out the list here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

Comment: Should that `^` go outside the group? As written it would match `//` in the not-starting position (so a relative URL like `#//` would match). Also, it's important to specify that this regex should be case-insensitive, so the complete definition would look like `/^(?:[a-z][a-z0-9+.-]*:|\/\/)/i`.

Comment: Id reckon that one-character schemes should be considered drive letters. So Id replace `*` with `+`.

Comment: Your regex matches `//cdn.example.com/lib.js` which is a relative-uri, not an absolute URI: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-4.2 "A relative reference that begins with two slash characters is termed a network-path reference;"

Answer (score 11):

You can use a try, catch block to help with this. Rather than using a regular expression, you can use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) interface at every step.

```
isExternalUrl (urlString) {
  try {
    const url = new URL(urlString) // THROW ON MISSING SCHEME

    // DOES THIS URL ORIGINATE FROM THIS WEBSITE?
    if (url.origin !== new URL(document.URL, document.baseURI).origin) {
      return true // IS EXTERNAL URL
    }
  } catch (_e) {
    // THROWS WHEN URL DOES NOT HAVE A SCHEME
    new URL(urlString, document.baseURL) // THROW AN EXCEPTION IF THE URL IS TRULY MALFORMED IN SOME WAY
  }

  return false
}
```

Comment: After 8 years, this is the best answer

Answer (score 10):

Nowdays, when a lot of services use [protocol-relative URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just) (eg. *//cdn.example.com/libary.js*), this method is safer:

```
var isAbsolute = new RegExp('^([a-z]+://|//)', 'i');

if (isAbsolute.test(urlString)) {
  // go crazy here
}
```

Comment: To catch urls like 'HTTP://WWW.GOOGLE.COM' you should use `'^([A-Za-z]+://|//)'`

Comment: Just set `i` flag to ignore case. Answer edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Don't use low-level stuff like regexp etc. These things have been solved by so many other people. Especially the edge cases.

Have a look at [URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/), it should do the job: http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html#is

```
var uri = new URI("http://example.org/");
uri.is("absolute") === true;
```

Comment: Useful if you had a lot of manipulations to do, but seems like overkill to use a JS library just for this.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a pretty robust solution for the browser environment:

**Let the browser handle everything.** No need for some complicated/error prone regexes.

```
const isAbsoluteUrl = (url) => {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  return link.origin + link.pathname + link.search + link.hash === url;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var external = RegExp('^(https?:)?//');
if(external.test(el)){
    // do something
}
```

EDIT:

With the next regular expression, you can even check if the link goes to the same domain or to an external one:

```
var external = RegExp('^((f|ht)tps?:)?//(?!' + location.host + ')');
if(external.test(el)){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: You need to escape the `.` characters that will almost certainly be in the hostname. Otherwise foo.example.com will also match fooXexample.com

Answer (score 2):

```
var adress = 'http://roflmao.com';
if (adress.substr(0,7) == 'http://' || adress.substr(0,8) == 'https://') {
    //
}
```

Comment: yeah that's true. I don't use regex cause I suck at it. Anyways, won't Http be converted into http in modern browsers?

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the mentioned solutions solved a `redirect_url` hack where the hacker entered `/\/example.com` or `/\\/example.com`. This is what I came up with to determine if our redirect url was relative:

```
var isRelative = !redirectUrl.match(/(\:|\/\\*\/)/);  // Don't allow "//" (with optional "\"'s) or ":"
```

Answer (score 1):

It should not start with a slash or hash, and it should not contain a double slash if not preceded by question mark or hash? I would not test that with a single regexp, it would be very complicated to match "no double slash".

```
function test(s) {
    return s.charAt(0) != "#"
      && s.charAt(0) != "/"
      && ( s.indexOf("//") == -1 
        || s.indexOf("//") > s.indexOf("#")
        || s.indexOf("//") > s.indexOf("?")
    );
}
```

would be easier, clearer and imho faster.

Answer (score 1):

Rationale for this late answer: The question phrasing makes two separate questions and we have many problematic answers on both accounts. First of all, /1.html is an absolute path. However, in the question text, it is stated that the links with protocol included should be tested. I will answer both (checking absolute path and testing for protocol).

```
function hasProtocol(path) {
    return /^\w+:/.test(path)
}

function isAbsolutePath(path) {
    return path.startsWith("/") || hasProtocol(path);
}
```

Some examples:

```
console.log(isAbsolutePath("FILE:/1.html"));
console.log(isAbsolutePath("/1.html"));
console.log(isAbsolutePath("1.html"));
console.log(isAbsolutePath("relative/to/1.html"));
console.log(isAbsolutePath("mailto:1.html"));
console.log(isAbsolutePath("https://example.com/1.html"));

console.log(hasProtocol("FILE:/1.html"));
console.log(hasProtocol("/1.html"));
console.log(hasProtocol("1.html"));
console.log(hasProtocol("relative/to/1.html"));
console.log(hasProtocol("mailto:1.html"));
console.log(hasProtocol("https://example.com/1.html"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Following function will get called when click event occurs on a hyperlink i.e 'a' tag if the tag contains url will be relative or contains same host then that new page will get loaded into same browser tab, If it contains different url then page will load in new browser tab

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){

        var a = this;
        var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
        var regex = new RegExp('^(?:[a-z]+:)?//', 'i');     

        if(a.host == location.host || regex.test(a_href) == false){
            a.target = '_self';
        }else{
            a.target = '_blank';
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var isExternalURL = url.toLowerCase().indexOf('http://') === 0 || url.toLowerCase().indexOf('https://') === 0 ;
```

Answer (score -2):

Using the standard [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) constructor can help:

```
const url = new URL(urlToTest);
const isAbsolute = url.protocol && url.hostname
```

and as a bonus it will check if your value is a valid URL.