# Regex check if given string is relative URL

Tags: python, regex

First, I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687099/how-to-test-if-a-url-string-is-absolute-or-relative) about how to check if string is an absolute or relative URL. My problem is I need a regex to check if a given string is a **relative** URL or not, i.e. I need a regex to check if a string does not start with any protocol or double slash `//`.

Actually, I am doing web scraping with *Beautiful Soup* and I want to retrieve all relative links. *Beautiful Soup* uses this syntax:

```
soup.findAll(href=re.compile(REGEX_TO_MATCH_RELATIVE_URL))
```

So, that's why I need this.

Test cases are

```
about.html
tutorial1/
tutorial1/2.html
/
/experts/   
../ 
../experts/ 
../../../   
./  
./about.html
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: You're aware that all your test cases are relative paths? Maybe blend in some absolute paths too for some reasonable testing...

Comment: I am not very familiar with python but maybe this package can help you: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Comment: And how is this question different from the link you provided?

Comment: maybe [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) can help you. Check if some parts (url attributes, e.g. scheme, netloc) are empty

Comment: My answer would be controversial probably, but I would avoid regex whenever possible if it's production code because 9 times out of 10, the next coder won't know regex or will need to stare a it too long to determine what is going on--especially if there are so many possibilities. Start with a comprehensive list of protocols and have one function check for recognized ones. Have another function check for unc paths, unix paths, drive letters, and then have a list of test strings to shove through. The readability will be easier than regex, but regex is fine for use on the fly.

Comment: Palu Macil is right, have a look at a [sample regex](https://regex101.com/r/fW9eM4/1) - are you sure you want that?

Comment: @stribizhev yup exactly i want this please do this as a answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you find it helpful, I am posting my suggestion.

The regular expression can be:

```
^(?!www\.|(?:http|ftp)s?://|[A-Za-z]:\\|//).*
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fW9eM4/1)

Note that it is becoming more and more unreadable if you start adding exclusions or more alternatives. Thus, perhaps, use VERBOSE mode (declared with `re.X`):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r"""^                    # At the start of the string, ...
                   (?!                  # check if next characters are not...
                      www\.             # URLs starting with www.
                     |
                      (?:http|ftp)s?:// # URLs starting with http, https, ftp, ftps
                     |
                      [A-Za-z]:\\       # Local full paths starting with [drive_letter]:\  
                     |
                      //                # UNC locations starting with //
                   )                    # End of look-ahead check
                   .*                   # Martch up to the end of string""", re.X)
print(p.search("./about.html"));          # => There is a match
print(p.search("//dub-server1/mynode"));  # => No match
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/c6Sd54)

The other  Washington Guedes's regexes

1. `^([a-z0-9]*:|.{0})\/\/.*$` - matches

   - `^` - beginning of the string
   - `([a-z0-9]*:|.{0})` - 2 alternatives:
   - `[a-z0-9]*:` - 0 or more letters or digits followed with `:`
   - `.{0}` - an empty string
   - `\/\/.*` - `//` and 0 or more characters other than newline (note you do not need to escape `/` in Python)
   - `$` - end of string

So, you can rewrite it as `^(?:[a-z0-9]*:)?//.*$`. he `i` flag should be used with this regex.

2. `^[^\/]+\/[^\/].*$|^\/[^\/].*$` - is not optimal and has 2 alternatives

Alternative 1:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\/]+` - 1 or more characters other than `/`
- `\/` - Literal `/`
- `[^\/].*$` - a character other than `/` followed by any 0 or more characters other than a newline

Alternative 2:

- `^` - start of string
- `\/` - Literal `/`
- `[^\/].*$` - a symbol other than `/` followed by any 0 or more characters other than a newline up to the end of string.

It is clear that the whole regex can be shortened to `^[^/]*/[^/].*$`. The `i` option can safely be removed from the regex flags.

Comment: Please check, and let me know if you need more assistance with it.

Comment: thank you so much this is what i need but can u compare ur and @washington solution??

Comment: Done, please look. I'd say his second regex  is very generic. My approach is to check what is not allowed, his is allow anything that resembles a relative URL, just 1 `/` is required. You can actually merge these 2 approaches, BTW, just add my lookahead to the 2nd improved version: `^(?!www\.|(?:http|ftp)s?://|[A-Za-z]:\\|//)[^/]*/[^/].*$`.

Comment: ohh thank u bt there is so many regex now :D which one i choose ?

Answer (score 2):

To match absolutes:

```
/^([a-z0-9]*:|.{0})\/\/.*$/gmi
```

[Live testing here.](https://regex101.com/r/jA4fZ9/1)

---

And to match relatives:

```
/^[^\/]+\/[^\/].*$|^\/[^\/].*$/gmi
```

[Live testing here.](https://regex101.com/r/jA4fZ9/2)

Comment: brother i want to match relative urls ur is matching absolute urls

Comment: thank you so much your `regex` is also working out of the box

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this one, it captures more edge cases:

`(?:url\(|<(?:link|script|img)[^>]+(?:src|href)\s*=\s*)(?!['"]?(?:data|http))['"]?([^'"\)\s>]+)`

Source: https://www.regextester.com/94254