# Typescript variable "does not appear in current scope"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to use the following code:

```
$('body').bind('ajaxSend', function (elm, xhr, s) {
    if (s.hasContent && securityToken) {   // handle all verbs with content
        var tokenParam = "__RequestVerificationToken=" + encodeURIComponent(securityToken);
        s.data = s.data ? [s.data, tokenParam].join("&") : tokenParam;
        // ensure Content-Type header is present!
        if (s.contentType !== false || options.contentType) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", s.contentType);
        }
    }
});
```

I found this in the post [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074199/jquery-ajax-calls-and-the-html-antiforgerytoken)

With typescript I get a syntax error on "options" saying "the name options does not appear in the current scope.

Can someone help and explain why I am getting this error. I see options is not declared and wonder where it comes from if it's not declared.

Answer (score 0):

It's just like with JavaScript where, at run-time, any enclosing function scopes and then the global scope are searched for an `options` variable and if it isn't found anywhere an exception is thrown because it's not defined.

So presumably, in the example code you pulled this from, you should assume that `options` is defined elsewhere, and you'd need to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the slight mistake is that this line:

```
 if (s.contentType !== false || options.contentType) {
```

Should actually be:

```
 if (s.contentType !== false || s.contentType) {
```

As your parameter `s` is the `ajaxOptions` passed to your function by jQuery.