# Call Delete post from view in mvc4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to call `[HttpPost] Delete` from the view. on click I want load jQuery dialog and call post action method.

It seems it looking for Delete view which I deleted. I just kept the code for [HttpPost] to process.

### index view

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  @{
     @Html.TryPartial("_actions", model)
        <li> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id =model.Id})</li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id =model.Id},new { @class = "delete-link" })</li>
  }
  </ul>
```

### Controller

```
 [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Byte[] id)
        {

            var committeeMember = db.Committee_Member.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Committee_Member_Id == id);

            if (committeeMember != null)
            {
                committeeMember.Cancelled = 1;
                db.Entry(committeeMember).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                Success("Your activity was deleted!");
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = committeeMember.Customer_Number });
            }

            Error("there were some errors in your form.");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Once I click on the `Delete` link page automatically redirecting to `Delete` view without jQuery dialog.

url is
http://company.com:55253/Member/Delete/AAAAAAICyns%3d

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Member/Delete/AAAAAAICyns=

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

How to call directly Delete post without redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hitting the action with `GET` instead of `POST`.

Try

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
}
```

in place of

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"}, 
          new { @class = "delete-link" , id =model.Id })
```

Comment: @James123, use a form or ajax.actionlink post method

Comment: Thanks, @DaveA. My only concern is that he now has a button instead of a regular hyperlink, so your suggestion of using `@Ajax.ActionLink()` is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should use RoutLink for this

```
@Html.RouteLink(linkname: "Delete", routeName:"DeleteMember", objectRouteValues: new {id =model.Id},objectHtmlValues: new { @class = "delete-link" })
```

In your RouteConfig class

```
   routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "DeleteMember",
                 url: "Delete/{id}",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Member", action = "DeleteConfirmed" }
                   );
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click `Delete` link you just navigating to this url with `GET` retuest. You should disable default link action and I think it's better to use jquery ajax, without extra forms and microsoft ajax helpers.

This question is what you need: [jQuery Ajax calls and the Html.AntiForgeryToken()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074199/jquery-ajax-calls-and-the-html-antiforgerytoken)

Because without `__RequestVerificationToken` you will get error, even using `POST` request.