# Any issue with posting a form to a controller using JQuery's serialize method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, security, serialization, jquery-post

I am using Ajax to post a form from my view to a controller and using `$("#formid").serialize()` to serialize the form values. Are there any security issues or performance issues in serializing the form prior to posting it?

Would it make sensitive data such as a SSN on the form vulnerable to any kind of security risk ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be posting Social Security Numbers on your site, I would highly recommend having a certificate installed so that the communication is encrypted.

Comment: Thanks !! Apart from that do you see any performance issues ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @bdarrow1021. 
If you want security you should use an encrypted communication.

One thing you can use is MVC anti-forgery token to prevent cross-site request forgeries.
What you have to do is wrap your action method with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` and the form's serialization should do the rest.

You can find a detailed explanation [here](http://www.bipinjoshi.net/articles/20e546b4-3ae9-416b-878e-5b12434fe7a6.aspx) and [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/), and some techniques regarding how to implement the anti-forger token in an ajax call in this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4074199/219406).

In terms of performance I don't think you're going to see any difference.