# Need some guide line for AntiForgeryToken use in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, antiforgerytoken

i am new in mvc. so i go through few article about AntiForgeryToken usage. AntiForgeryToken emit a encrypted value in page and when form post then encrypted value & cookie for AntiForgeryToken goes to server end and there compare two value to check the both are same or not. if not then a error is thrown.

i have few question on AntiForgeryToken

1) how comparision occur at server end. do i need to write any code to compare value or it is done automatically when action method having attribute like [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()] ?

[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public ActionResult Edit(ProductDetails productdetails)
{

}

2) if i like to encrypt user id when page display then can write the code like `@Html.AntiForgeryToken(m=> m.userid)` ? if it is possible then when form will post then how can get the user id value from server side because user id would be encrypted.

3) what is salt concept people use ? how to implement salt concept with `AntiForgeryToken()` ?

4) can i put multiple `AntiForgeryToken()` in single form for encrypting multiple sensitive data ? if not possible then please tell me the reason.

5) how can i make `AntiForgeryToken()` encrypt value against a key....the key will be supplied by me and every time it will be dynamic ?

please give answer point wise. thanks

### UPDATE

regarding dynamic salt

To generate a random string, use the RNGCryptoServiceProvider.

```
public string GenerateSalt(int length)
{
    var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    var buffer = new byte[length];
    rng.GetBytes(buffer);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
}
```

if i call GenerateSalt() then it will always give a dynamic combinatio. that it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074199/jquery-ajax-calls-and-the-html-antiforgerytoken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Done automatically. That's what `[validateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute (filter) does.
2. That's not within the scope of the token; it's there just to prevent spam and some forms of hacking, not to encrypt data. if security is a concern, think of creating your own Data Annotation attribute coupled with a DisplayTemplate/EditorTemplate (then also a custom filter to pre-process the incoming value).
3. Salt is like any form of encryption; it's there to make it more difficult to spoof incoming values. By using a salt you're adding another level of complication to the hash so decrypting now requires that value.
4. Again, it's not there to encrypt *your* data, just to secure the form form misuse.
5. Not sure what you mean--a dynamic salt? You can probably create a custom implementation (`ValidateMyAntiForgeryToken : ValidateAntiForgeryToken`).

Comment: i update my question. also tell is there any good article exist for ValidateMyAntiForgeryToken custom AntiForgeryToken ?