# Ajax Post not recognizing my AntiForgeryToken

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

I'm trying to do an $.ajax post with this code:

```
$('button#removeTeamMember').click(function() {
        var thisPlayerId = $(this).attr('data-bind').valueOf();
        var thisTeamId = $('#hidden').text();
    alert("PlayerId: " + thisPlayerId + " TeamId: " + thisTeamId);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Teams/RemoveTeamMember",
        data: AddAntiForgeryToken({ playerId: thisPlayerId, teamId: thisTeamId }),
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(returnedData) {
            if (returnedData.success === true) {
                window.location = "/Teams/Details?id=" + thisTeamId;
            } else {
                alert("An error occurred removing the team member.");
            }
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("jqxhr: " + jqxhr.readyState + "; " + jqxhr.status + "; " + jqxhr.responseText);
            alert("textStatus: " + textStatus);
            alert("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        },
        async: false
    });
});
```

And here's my controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult RemoveTeamMember(int playerId, int teamId)
{
    var teamMember = _teamMemberRepository.Query().FirstOrDefault(tm => tm.Player.PlayerId == playerId && tm.Team.TeamId == teamId);
    _teamMemberRepository.Delete(teamMember);

    //return RedirectToAction("Details");
    return Json(new {success = true});
}
```

Here's the view code:

```
<form method="POST" action="#" role="form">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h3>@Model.Team.TeamName</h3></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Player Type</th>
                                <th>Player</th>
                                <th>Handicap</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Manager</td>
                                <td>@Html.ActionLink(@Model.Team.TeamManager.DisplayName, "#")</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>

                            @foreach (var teamMember in @Model.Team.TeamMembers)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Player</td>
                                    <td><a href="#">@teamMember.Player.DisplayName</a></td>
                                    <td>Handicap</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button id="removeTeamMember" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-bind="@teamMember.Player.PlayerId">Remove</button>
                                        <div id="hidden" style="visibility: hidden">@teamMember.Team.TeamId</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I'm getting the error back saying the AntiForgeryToken is not present, even though it's getting called via the "AddAntiForgeryToken" which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074199/jquery-ajax-calls-and-the-html-antiforgerytoken). What else am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AddAntiForgeryToken` function from the [answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074199/jquery-ajax-calls-and-the-html-antiforgerytoken) assumes that your AntiForgeryToken hidden field input has a container (the form) with this id: `__AjaxAntiForgeryForm`. You don't have that. Either remove the id from the selector and replace it with `form` for example:

```
$('form input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
```

Or add the id to the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="#" role="form" id="__AjaxAntiForgeryForm">
```

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you have added the anti forgery to view.

You must have the following in current razor page.

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

This will render the correct html token into the page, AddAntiForgeryToken will select this element and insert it into your ajax data.