# Execute controller action with Dojo sending the AntiForeignKey in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dojo

How can I execute a controller action in ASP.NET MVC4 sending the anti foreign key too?

My request is formed as follow code snippet:

```
var _antiForeignKey = dojoQuery('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', dojo.byId('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm'))[0].value;

xhr.post({
   url: 'Account/LogOff',
   handleAs: 'json',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   postData: '__RequestVerificationToken=' + _antiForeignKey 
});
```

And I receive an error from server with a html which contains the

> The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is
>   not present.

message as response. Obviously, the action in the controller is not executed.

I've seen this post: [jQuery Ajax calls and the Html.AntiForgeryToken()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074199/jquery-ajax-calls-and-the-html-antiforgerytoken), which answers my question but using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got to execute the controller action by using the previous code snippet but modifying the value of two parameters, `'handleAs'` and `'contentType'`:

```
var _antiForeignKey = dojoQuery('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', dojo.byId('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm'))[0].value;

xhr.post({
   url: 'Account/LogOff',
   handleAs: 'text',
   contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   postData: '__RequestVerificationToken=' + _antiForeignKey        
});
```

As you can see, I've changed the `'handleAs'` property because we are not handling json data in the response, and the `'contentType'` to specify we are sending other type of data as request's parameter.