# Why my ajax is not sending image uploaded on the controller side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am sending a model along with the image to my controller using jquery ajax.
here is my form.

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "CreateUser" ,enctype = "multipart/form-data" } ))
        {

            @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
              @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
               <fieldset>
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        @*----FIRST NAME----*@
                        <label>
                            First Name <span class="text-red font12">*</span>
                        </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtFirstName", @maxlength = "30" })
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        @*----LAST NAME----*@
                        <label>
                            Last Name <span class="text-red font12">*</span>
                        </label>

                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtLastName", @maxlength = "30" })
                    </div>

               <div class="col-xs-6">
                        @*----Logo Upload----*@

                        <label>
                           Logo Uploaad <span class="text-red font12">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="input-group">


                            <input type="file" id="FileUpload1" />

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

        <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4" style="float:right;">
                        <input type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" onclick="validateandcreate();" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

}
here is my jquery code

```
function CreateUser() {

    var username = $("#txtUserName").val();

    var fileUpload = $("#FileUpload1").get(0);
    var files = fileUpload.files;

    var fileData = new FormData();  

    // Looping over all files and add it to FormData object  
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {  
        fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);  
    }  


    debugger;
    if (username != "") {

        var model = {
            "FirstName": encodeURIComponent($("#txtFirstName").val()),
            "LastName": encodeURIComponent($("#txtLastName").val())
        };


        $.ajax({
            url: '/User/Create',
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { m: model, f: fileData },
            success: function (data) {
              alert("success");
            },
            error: function (err) {

               alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

it is working perfectly if i am sending only the model,but does not hit the controller if I send the uploaded image along with it.
here is my contrller.

```
   [HttpPost]
    //[AuthorizationFilter]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Create(Models.Users user, HttpPostedFileBase file_Uploader)
    {
   //code
    }
```

Comment: Note you also need to give the file input `name="file_Uploader"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `processData: false` and `contentType: false` on your ajax to submit files through [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

You can also add data other than files into your `FormData`.

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file", fileobject);
formdata.append("model", JSON.stringify({
  name: "Johny",
  lastname: "Good"
}));

$.ajax({
  url: '/User/Create',
  method: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  data: formdata,
  success: function(data) {
    alert("success");
  },
  error: function(err) {

    alert("error");
  }
});
```

See [Ajax File Uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: but I want to pass both  i.e model(firstname,lastname) and filedata(uploaded image) in a single ajax post

Comment: the above solution is working only if i am sending the uploaded image to the controller

Comment: You can add as much data as you want into your formdata. append your modal object to formdata as a stringified json and parse it server-side, or append its key-value pairs into formdata as seperate key-value pairs. Whichever you perefer works. I updated the answer showing how to send other data along with files.

Comment: I am getting only this error on the clientside now.i.e fdata is not defined while posting through ajax

Comment: I have used and var fdata = new FormData(); though

Comment: That error would be thrown because `fdata` is not defined when you try to reach it. Make sure you define it before you try to reach it and it is reachable. Without the rest of your code and exact line the error is thrown I can't tell more.

Comment: I was using ValidateAntiForgeryToken which was causing the problem.I removed that token and it worked absolutly fine. thanks man.

Comment: If you want to use AntiForgeryToken with ajax forms, you can make it work with a little bit of manual work. Get the tokens value from the form you put it in and append it to the formdata with the key `__RequestVerificationToken`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074199/jquery-ajax-calls-and-the-html-antiforgerytoken for more details.