# how to close modal popup bootstrap and update datatable after ajax call in asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have used `datatable` library along with two buttons edit and delete.when I submit the form (modal popup bootstrap ).it doesn't close and I have to close it manually as well I have to refresh manually my "datatable" to showing my manipulations.I have two problems.1)modal popup doesn't close and 2) `datatable` doesn't refresh.

[image]
    @model Dentistry.Areas.ViewModels.UserViewModel

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">ویرایش کاربران</h4>

</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Users", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "popupForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    if (Model != null && Model.UserId != string.Empty)
    {
        <div class="modal-body" id="editModal">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.UserId)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>نام کاربری</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>نام</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.FirstName)
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>نام خانوادگی</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.LastName)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>جنسیت</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Gender, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Gender)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>وضعیت</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.IsActive, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.IsActive)
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>ایمیل</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Email)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>آدرس</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Address, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Address)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>شماره تماس</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.PhoneNumber)
            </div>

            @*<a href="#" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">ویرایش</a>*@
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" >ویرایش</button>
            @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>*@
        </div>
    }
}
<script>
    //$(document).ready(function () {


        $(function () {
            $('#popupForm').on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("hi");
                SubmitForm();
            })
        });
        function SubmitForm() {
            var data = $("#popupForm").serialize();
            var url = "/Users/Edit";
            var form = $('#popupForm')[0];
            var formdata = false;
            if (window.FormData) {
                formdata = new FormData(form);
            }
            alert(formdata);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: url,
                data: formdata ? formdata : data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                //  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == true) {
                        $('#edit').modal('hide');
                        window.location.href="/Users/Index";
                        $("#myDatatable").ajax.reload();
                    }
                }

            });
        }

</script>
```

============================================

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(UserViewModel user)
{
    bool status=false;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userQuery=db.User.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id  == user.UserId);
        if (user.UserId != string.Empty)
        {
            userQuery.FirstName = user.FirstName;
            userQuery.LastName = user.LastName;
            userQuery.PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber;
            userQuery.UserName = user.UserName;
            userQuery.Email = user.Email;
            userQuery.Address = user.Address;
            userQuery.Gender = Convert.ToBoolean(user.Gender);
            userQuery.IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(user.IsActive);
        }
        else
        {
            User userDB=new User();
            userDB = userQuery;
            db.User.Add(userDB);
        }
        //  db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        status = true;

    }
   // return RedirectToAction("Index");
    // return View(user);
    return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the ajax method is not returning success.  Check the network tab on the browser and see.

Comment: @nurdyguy, yes exactly, my ajax method doesn't work.I added alert into success function it doesn't fire.

Comment: What does it say in the networks tab?  Anything?  Just because it didn't get to `success` doesn't mean it didn't fire.  You should always have an `error: function() {...}` method, even if you don't do anything with it.

Comment: @nurdyguy, in my network tab, it returned 'status: true'.I've added a picture to my question.

Comment: From that picture it looks like it is returning ok.  Change `if (data == true)` to `if (data.status == true)`.  If that doesn't work, put a debug stop on the same line as the `if`, _before_ you enter the block.

Comment: @nurdyguy, thanks a lot.it works fine.did you know how many hours does it take to be fixed? 12 hours.you rock.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149745/discussion-between-rayan-and-nurdyguy).

Answer (score 2):

You response should be something like

```
return Json(new{success =true},JsonRequestBehaviour.DenyGet);
```

and in client side

```
  success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        $('#edit').modal('hide');
                        window.location.href="/Users/Index";
                                          }
                }
```

you may want to add an error function to just to know

Answer (score 1):

Your response from MVC is an object with the property `success` on it so in your jQuery you need to be testing `if(data.success == true)`.  Since it is a boolean you could also just do `if(data.success)` as a shortcut.

Comment: and also you dont need datatable.reload since you are changing the windows.location

Comment: Yeah that's a good point.  Either reload the table _or_ reload the page, don't need to do both.  Though if I was going to navigate away from the page I'd do a regular form submit rather than ajax.

Comment: true all he need was to just add the new row dynamically and call the draw extinsion function,the problem with this code is that imagine if the datatable ajax call is sync then the page has to wait for that ajaxload to happen then it will relocate

Comment: They are using `.ajax.reload()` which is async by default so they should be ok.  I personally don't really like entity framework nor datatables, but for someone just learning C# MVC, this is a good exercise.